# Conversion ways from hashmap to hashtable

Tags: java

I am using the following program for converting from hashmap to hashtable
I used two different methods for converting, one is giving ht1 and other is giving ht2

What is the difference between ht1 and ht2?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

public class HashMapToHashTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Map <Integer,Integer>hm = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        hm.put(1, 2);
        hm.put(3, 4);
        System.out.println(hm.keySet());
        //First way of converting hashmap to hashtable
        Map <Integer, Integer>ht1 = new Hashtable<Integer,Integer>(hm);
        System.out.println(ht1.keySet());
        //Second way of converting hashmap to hashtable
        Map <Integer, Integer>ht2 = new Hashtable<Integer,Integer>();
        ht2.putAll(hm);   
        System.out.println(ht2.keySet());       
    }
}
```

Will this Collections.synchronizedMap(hm) also be used to convert from hashmap to hashtable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is very simple, don't use a `HashTable`.

This is a deprecated collection kept around for backwards compatibility. `Collections.synchronizedMap` is indeed the current replacement for `HashTable`, but it's next to useless unless you are doing very specific things. `ConcurrentHashMap` is almost always a better default choice.

Directly from the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

> If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to
>   use `HashMap` in place of `Hashtable`. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent
>   implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use
>   `ConcurrentHashMap` in place of Hashtable.

For conversion, `ConcurrentHashMap` has a [copy constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#ConcurrentHashMap%28java.util.Map%29):

```
Map<Integer,Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer,Integer> chm = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(hm);
```

Comment: _This is a deprecated collection_ In my opinion it might be a bit misleading. The class itself is not deprecated according to Java Docs API, neither the use of it. Please consider removing this word or place in quotes. Thanks.

Comment: @kasur I would say this it _is_ a deprecated collection and its use _is_ deprecated. The fact that it's not `@Deprecated` is irrelevant - that is only because Oracle do not plan to remove it from the JDK. You should not use `HashTable` in new code.

Comment: I do find the usage of this collection questionable at the moment as well. However, the point of mine was that as soon as one makes a reference to _official documentation_ regarding HashMap, the usage of words _deprecated_ and _backward compatibility_ in the same context might be misleading and should be emphasized as your own opinion. Also, there is no such a collection as _HashTable_ in Java API.